# Why doesn't the Swift 1.2 compiler enforce type-checking for AnyObject?

Tags: swift, types

Update: See summary below

I am working my way through converting a program from Swift 1.1 to 1.2. As part of that, I came across this (imperfect) code:

```
func encode2(n:String, v:AnyObject)->String {
    var result:String = ""
    let n2 = n.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let v2 = v.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    result = n2! + "=" + v2!
    return result
}
```

Among other problems, if `encode2` is called with parameter `v` any type other than `String`, this program crashes at runtime (unsurprisingly) with an `unrecognised selector` message. The Swift compiler could have avoided this crash by making me check it was a string, like this, for example:

```
if let v = v as? String {
    let v2 = v.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    ...
}
```

Given that Swift 1.2 is so picky about making me use `as!` for downcasting, I was a bit surprised it didn't make me type-check `AnyObject` at runtime, or at least warn me that I hadn't done it.

**Is there some fundamental reason why the compiler omits this requirement**,

or **has Apple just not got around to it yet?**

**Update** After answers here and at the Apple Forum.

The strategy does seem a bit odd, but is consistent with the Swift documentation. If you define a variable as `AnyObject`, then the compiler assumes you know it is dangerous. If you compute a variable that turns out to be an `AnyObject`, the compiler warns you:

[image: Error message]

However, if you call a method on an `AnyObject`, the compiler always assumes that you know what you're doing, and says nothing.

The "Using Swift With Cocoa and Objective C" book explicitly suggests writing `?` after the method name,

```
if let v2 = v.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding?(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
     // ...
}
```

to turn the result into an absent optional rather than crash if the method is not present. But the compiler doesn't enforce it.

This seems very un-Swifty to me but it's the case for the time being.

Comment: I had also wondered about that. In Objective-C, you can send arbitrary messages to `id` (as long as the signature is somehow known to the compiler), but I don't see why this should be possible in Swift. You could ask at the developer forum https://devforums.apple.com/community/tools/languages/swift.

Comment: Thanks! I posted one here: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/267750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AnyObject` is a Swift version of `id`, from [the document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_30):

> Swift includes a protocol type named `AnyObject` that represents any kind of object, just as `id` does in Objective-C. The `AnyObject` protocol allows you to write type-safe Swift code while maintaining the flexibility of an untyped object. Because of the additional safety provided by the `AnyObject` protocol, Swift imports `id` as `AnyObject`.

If you want:

> You can take advantage of optionals in Swift to eliminate this common Objective-C error from your code. When you call an Objective-C method on an `AnyObject` type object, the method call actually behaves like an implicitly unwrapped optional. **You can use the same optional chaining syntax** you would use for optional methods in protocols to optionally invoke a method on AnyObject.

In your case, you can:

```
if let v2 = v.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding?(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    // ...                                             ^
}
```

But I'd also wondered why it's NOT `Optional`, but `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`.

In Cocoa API Reference, in API parameters, we often see `Error!`, `AnyObject!`, `String!`, and so on... As for Objective-C interoperation, It seems, the default is *"implicitly unwrapped optionals"*, [as documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_32):

> In some cases, you might be absolutely certain that an Objective-C method or property never returns a `nil` object reference. To make objects in this special scenario more convenient to work with, Swift imports object types as implicitly unwrapped optionals.

That is, **it's for "convenience"**.

Comment: I was actually more concerned about the case where the object was present but wasn't the right type. You're correct to point out that I can just put a `?` after the function name, and that's very neat. But I'm still surprised that I am not warned by the compiler if I miss it out. Let's see if anyone else has any better ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because that's what `AnyObject` is designed to do.

Quoting from [id Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_30) (the parts after what rintaro quoted in his answer):

> **You can also call any Objective-C method and access any property
>   without casting to a more specific class type.** This includes
>   Objective-C compatible methods marked with the @objc attribute.
>
> However, because the specific type of an object typed as AnyObject is
>   not known until runtime, it is possible to inadvertently write unsafe
>   code. As in Objective-C, **if you invoke a method or access a property
>   that does not exist on an AnyObject typed object, it is a runtime
>   error.** For example, the following code compiles without complaint and
>   then causes an unrecognized selector error at runtime:

Comment: rintaro gets the tick because they were first, so you get a +1 because you were helpful too. Thanks!